Pop up for Country Selection in Website for SEO?
Our eCommerce website operates in two countries: Canada and the USA. The site is organized based on stores, rather than currency. We are using a pop-up for country selection, allowing users to choose between Canada and the USA. If a user visits a page intended for the USA but is located in Canada, the pop-up appears and prompt them to switch to the store based on their current location. Is this a good practice from an SEO perspective?
In desktop:

In Mobile

Additionally, will this pop-up affect the visibility of our website on both mobile and desktop devices?.
Please suggest the best practise.

Hi!! Welcome to UXSE. There are two parts to the question where the 2nd part fits our scope but we would love it if you could edit it a bit – to be specific – please explain further on "affect the visibility" and what are your concerns around that in detail. As for part 1, matters relating to SEO are out of scope of UXSE and would be a better fit in webmasters.stackexchange.com.
